# rose diagram based on group and color it based on group in r

Tags: r

I have a data in degrees of three different groups. I managed to draw rose diagram using circular package but i want to color and label the rose diagram based on group. following is my data;

```
Value    Category
74.71    A
86.43    A
349.20   A
143.46   A
315.95   A
25.37    A
347.52   A
225.72   A
195.58   A
103.22   A
73.25    B
94.79    B
76.95    B
183.77   B
353.51   B
1.04     B
3.64     B
216.62   B
28.25    B
96.89    B
252.32   C
320.11   C
287.45   C
7.42     C
6.56     C
298.36   C
115.25   C
218.14   C
182.25   C
193.23   C
```

Following is my code;

```
data<-data.frame(rosediag[2:3])
angl<-data$Value
group<-data$Category
rose.diag(angl,bins = 30, main = "All Categories")
```

I want a rose diagram that shows A, B, C in different color and label them in a side bar. I want all 30 data points displayed on the rose diagram and color based on category.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQej6.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know whether this can be easily achieved with `circular`, but if you would be willing to use another package, below is an example of what you could get with `plotly` - is that what you are after?

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(plotly))
df <- data.frame(
    Value = c(74.71, 86.43, 349.2, 143.46, 315.95, 25.37, 347.52, 225.72, 
        195.58, 103.22, 73.25, 94.79, 76.95, 183.77, 353.51, 1.04, 3.64, 216.62,
        28.25, 96.89, 252.32, 320.11, 287.45, 7.42, 6.56, 298.36, 115.25, 
        218.14, 182.25, 193.23), 
    Category = rep(LETTERS[1:3], each=10))

with(df, plot_ly(color=Category, theta=Value, type='barpolar', r=1))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-05-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks this is what i was exactly after